# Should I always explicitly set width on floated items?

Tags: html, css

Here and there I see suggestions that I should *always* set width on floated items. But when I'm exploring CSS of popular web-services (such as Twitter/Google), I see that almost nobody does that.

Is it still considered good style to *always* set width on floated items? In which cases should I set 'width' property and when it can be safely omitted?

Some quotes:

[SmashingMagazine says that](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/):

> “You should always set a width on floated items (except if applied directly to an image – which has implicit width). If no width is set, the results can be unpredictable.”

[HTML and CSS: Design and Build Websites book says:](http://www.htmlandcssbook.com/)

> When you use the float property, you should also use the width property to indicate how wide the floated element should be. If you do not, results can be inconsistent but the box is likely to take up the full width of the containing element (just like it would in normal flow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it really depends on the browser, you must check the results in multiple browsers to be sure that none of them "misunderstood" your settings. I'd set a width anyway, because no browser can misunderstood that.

Answer (score 1):

Block element takes the full width of the parent. If you use float it will not take the full width, the width would be how much the element width it is.

Answer (score 1):

i use width with floating elements in percentage of the containing div , the only problem you get is that the containing div might not wrap arround its content , so you have to put on the main div overflow:auto